# How to split a nested list by first three commas? Python

Tags: python, dataframe, nested-lists

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['12345','23456','34567'],
     'Info':(['Rob Kardashian', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star'],
                  ['Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', '100','Best','TikTok Star'],
                 ['Stan Lee','35239856','1922-12-28','10','Best Publisher & Producer'])})
```

[image]

I have above dataframe and I want to split the values in column 'Info' by the first three commas.

The code below only works for splitting by all commas...

```
[[re.split(',', i) for i in w] for w in my_df['Info']]
```

The expected result:
[image]

Comment: in your list comprehension, just use `i.split(',', 3)` don't use `re`

Comment: But I still got the same outputs...

Comment: how about slicing: mylist[:2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple like this?

```
[[*x[:3], ', '.join(x[3:])] for x in my_df['Info']]
```

It would return this output:

`[['Rob Kardashian', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star'],
  ['Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', '100, Best, TikTok Star'],
  ['Stan Lee', '35239856', '1922-12-28', '10, Best Publisher & Producer']]`